# Nginx : Docker : AWS : ECS : 502 Bad Gateway : on first hit

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, containers

When I run this on the AWS Container service. Every time when it runs new container it fires a `502 Bad Gateway` error and on the second hit , it runs absolutely fine. But due initial `502 Bad Gateway` , it gives instability on the container start ups.

It happens only on the initial hit only.. Please help me improve the nginx docker which runs stable on the initial time or first hit

**docker file**

```
FROM nginx:latest

# Install only what is needed
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends curl \
      && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Remove default nginx
RUN rm /usr/share/nginx/html/*

# Copy all of our nginx configurations
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Copy our optimized build into the web folder that we point to in default.conf
COPY ./dist/ /var/www/
COPY ./robots.txt /var/www/

# Convenicne just in case we want to add more configuration later
COPY entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

# Daemon Off otherwise, Docker will drop when the main process is done making child ones
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**Default.conf**

```
server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  server_name xxx.yyy.com;
  root /var/www/;

  keepalive_timeout 60;

  # lightweight health check for load balancer
  location = /health-alb {
    access_log off;
    return 200 'A-OK!';
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
  }

  # for root, go to index
  location / {
    # This Configuration will redirect HTTP to HTTPS 
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

  # gzip static files
  location ~ ^/static/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
  }

  # Don't serve hidden files
  location ~ /\. {
    return 404;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
  }

  # Attempt to load the favicon or fall back to status code 204.
  location = /favicon.ico {
    try_files /favicon.ico = 204;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
  }
}
```

**nginx.conf**

```
# Auto Detect and set workers to number of cpu cores
worker_processes auto;

worker_rlimit_nofile 4096;

events {
  # Match T2 1 core with Worker Limit AND the open rlimit file.
  # Change based on the instance type you use, and the traffic you expect
  # Most public sites will hit 10k+ but you'll need to understand the traffic
  # Default is 768 if you want to remove it later
  worker_connections 4096;
}

http {
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  server_tokens off;

  # https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options
  add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

  add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

  # https://www.owasp.org/index.php/List_of_useful_HTTP_headers
  add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

  # Enabling the sendfile directive will eliminate the step of copying the
  # data into the buffer and enables direct copying data from one file
  # descriptor to another.
  sendfile on;

  # Optimize Amount of Data Sent at Once with sendfile
  tcp_nopush on;

  # http://nginx.org/en/docs/hash.html
  types_hash_max_size 2048;

  # Of Course Gzip
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";

  # Import our default.conf
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I don't mean to come off judgmental, but why all the technologies. It will help me understand.

Comment: I want to deploy docker on the ecs . I have set up all the environment , even I am able to restart my containers automatically via cluster. But When cluster server is triggering new container , nginx show 502 error on first load and  second load it works fine